# Having a null violation error when posting from my frontend to the server side in node.js and react and sequelize

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to link my frontend signup page with my backend but I am getting this null viloation error:

> ValidationErrorItem {
> message: 'user.username cannot be null',
> type: 'notNull Violation',
> path: 'username',
> value: null,
> origin: 'CORE',
> instance: [user],
> validatorKey: 'is_null',
> validatorName: null,
> validatorArgs: []
> },

I made sure that I am storing and sending the values I get but it still raising the null error
This is my controller for posting the user:

```
const User = require("../models/user");


    exports.postUser = (req, res, next) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  const user = User.build({
    username: username,
    email: email,
    password: password,
  });
  user
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

and this is my route:

```
const express = require("express");

const authController = require("../controllers/authentication");

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/signup", authController.postUser);
```

and here is the code from the frontend

```
const [usernameReg, setUsernameReg] = useState("");
  const [passwordReg, setPasswordReg] = useState("");
  const [emailReg, setEmailReg] = useState("");

  const register = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:5001/signup", {
      username: usernameReg,
      email: emailReg,
      password: passwordReg,
    })
      .then()
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

return (
    <Grid container direction="row">
      <Grid item container direction="column" justify="center" lg={4} xl={3}>
        <Grid item>
          <Grid container direction="column">
            <Grid item>
              <img src={Logo} className={classes.logo} alt="mahmool logo" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Typography variant="h2">Sign up</Typography>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item>
              <TextField
                label="Username"
                id="username"
                onChange={(event) => setUsernameReg(event.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <TextField
                label="Email"
                id="email"
                onChange={(event) => setEmailReg(event.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <TextField
                type="password"
                label="Password"
                id="password"
                onChange={(event) => setPasswordReg(event.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid>

            <Grid item>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
                className={classes.spacing}
                onClick={register}
              >
                Signup
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>

      <Grid container className={classes.carStyle} lg={8}>
        <img src={Car} className={classes.carStyle} alt="mahmool car" />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
```

Comment: Check your values(`usernameReg` , `emailReg` , `passwordReg`) In `register` function before `Axios. get ()`

Comment: I consoled their values right before the Axios and they were correct

Comment: check them also in `postUser` , Are there in `req.body`  or something else?

Comment: They appear as undefined in postUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your values in an object and send them to node

```
  const register = () => {
      const payload = {
          username: usernameReg,
          email: emailReg,
          password: passwordReg}

    Axios.post("http://localhost:5001/signup", payload)
```

if `payload`doesn't exist in req , check `console.log(req)`

```
    exports.postUser = (req, res, next) => {
        console.log(req.body.payload);
        const {username , email , password } = req.body.payload
    }
```

Comment: It worked well now and inserted the record. Thank you, very much appreciated!

Comment: @KhalidAlmubarak would love a "solved" marker :)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of this marker and solved let it be now on :)